# Scan from multifunction network printer

Tags: windows-8, printer, scanner, multi-function-printer

I have printer `HP LaserJet 3055` that is on network. I can print to it without problems, but I can't scan - windows 8 doesn't see it like scanner.

Previously it was connected using USB port to my PC and I was scanning with standard windows tools without problem.

How to configure system to scan from network printer?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the 3055 will only scan via USB. It is not able to scan to email, and network scanning to file is not supported. In addition, HP's scan software is not available for Windows 8. Scanning (via USB) is still possible via software like Paint, Windows Scan & Fax, or other software like Irfanview.

For more details, see the [data sheet](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fh10010.www1.hp.com%2Fwwpc%2Fpscmisc%2Fvac%2Fus%2Fproduct_pdfs%2F1161389.pdf&ei=ipEsVJezLIXyoAS0uoKQCg&usg=AFQjCNFNbupF09J7H1vfY7UmtcUebI6k8g&bvm=bv.76477589,d.cGU) and this hp support site:
http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c03501661-6%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken